# Rid system of old kernel...my usual approach doesn't work

Tags: kernel, lubuntu

On a PC that I updated from Ubuntu 12 to Lubuntu 14, an old kernel (3.13.0-62) shows up in the grub menu (seen here in grub-customizer):

[image]

It's really there, I think, because there are files in `/boot`:

```
abi-3.13.0-62-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.16.0-55-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-3.16.0-56-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-3.13.0-62-generic      System.map-3.13.0-62-generic
config-3.16.0-55-generic      System.map-3.16.0-55-generic
config-3.16.0-56-generic      System.map-3.16.0-56-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-62-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-55-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-55-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-56-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-56-generic
```

Now, I normally remove old kernels with Ubuntu-Tweak, or Synaptic, but this kernel doesn't show up in either:

[image]

So how can I get rid of this old kernel?  Should I just delete the files out of `/boot`?

Edit: `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-` produces the following output (3.13 kernel is not listed).

```
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-53-generic               3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1                   i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-55-generic               3.16.0-55.74~14.04.1                   i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-56-generic               3.16.0-56.75~14.04.1                   i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic         3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1                   i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-55-generic         3.16.0-55.74~14.04.1                   i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-56-generic         3.16.0-56.75~14.04.1                   i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic              3.16.0.56.47                           i386         Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: I can see 3.13.0-62 in your synaptic pic. Did you try removing it via [dpkg](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels)?

Comment: Yes, but the boxes aren't checked indicating that it is installed.  I did look at that page you linked to, but `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-` does not show the 3.13 kernel.  I'll put output of this command in the question, thanks for the idea.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: You don't need to `grep` the output of `dpkg -l`. You can just tell `dpkg` to filter the requested list: `dpkg -l linux-image-\*`

Comment: I'ld try forcing the package to install for the 3.13.0-62 kernel.  Then uninstalling it, and see if that sorts you out.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks!  That command comes straight from the 'removing old kernels' page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I don't find it to be a quality answer, but it fixed the OPs problem.  So, I moved it from the comments.*

I'ld try forcing the package to install for the 3.13.0-62 kernel. Then uninstalling it, and see if that sorts you out.